# Error: libtool - while compiling an MPI program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mpi, openmpi

I'm using `OpenSuse Leap` and I installed `openMPI` thought YaST. Running a `which mpirun` command I get `/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin/mpirun` and running `which mpicc` i get `/usr/bin/mpicc`.

How to make sure first that OpenMPI is correctly installed?

Second, I have a simple hello world I am process X program and running `mpicc hello.c` I get this output

> gcc: error: libtool:: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: link:: No
>
> such file or directory mpicc: No such file or directory

Also, I installed `Eclipse for Parallel Application` and used a build-in example and it gives me this output at build

> make all
>
> Building target: hello
>
> Invoking: GCC C Linker
>
> mpicc  -o "hello"  ./src/hello.o
>
> gcc: error: libtool:: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: link:: No such file or directory
>
> makefile:30: recipe for target 'hello' failed
>
> mpicc: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [hello] Error 1

I checked YaST and libtool is installed.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install automake autoconf libtool` and after `autoreconf -i`

Comment: Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libtool' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'libtool-2.4.2-16.6.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.
'automake' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'automake-1.13.4-6.4.noarch'. The highest available version is already installed.
'autoconf' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'autoconf-2.69-11.4.noarch'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.

Comment: @LPs About the +autoreconf -i how do I use it?

Comment: Did you tried to launch `autoreconf -i` in the project directory?

Comment: @LPs I did an `autoreconf -i` in terminal and got `autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required`

Comment: There is something wrong in your autotool project. Configure.ac is mandatory in  an autotool project.

Comment: @LPs not if he's building from a release tarball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer comes at a time too late. I recently had the same issue. Hence anyone who comes here for an answer, this was how I got it working.

Please note: this is an isolated situation who gets similar error

```
gcc: error: libtool:: No such file or directory

gcc: error: link:: No such file or directory

mpicc: No such file or directory
```

First try to check the solution suggested by LPs. It will try to update your libtool autoconf and automake. If you get nothing to do:

```
sudo zypper in automake autoconf libtool
root's password:
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libtool' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'libtool-2.4.2-15.2.2.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.
'autoconf' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'autoconf-2.69-10.1.2.noarch'. The highest available version is already installed.
'automake' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'automake-1.13.4-5.1.2.noarch'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Then explicitly add your OpemMPI path variable.

```
export PATH=/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:$PATH
```

This worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks! Although I can't confirm your answer, I moved to debian which work out of the box with no issues, I will approve it as correct.