# Compilation of MPI "hello world" fails

Tags: c, compiler-errors, mpi

Today I tried to compile the classical MPI "hello world" program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    printf("I am rank %d of %d\n", rank, size);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

To do so I installed openMPI, lam, lam-devel (for mpicc). I tried to follow the answer given in [this old thread adressing this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378437/error-libtool-while-compiling-an-mpi-program), which lead to an installation of automake, autoconf, libtool and from [here](http://linux-club.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=114063) I also came to install coreutils. Unfortunatelly I still get the following error-message when trying to compile the above code

```
mpicc hello.c   -o hello
gcc: error: libtool:: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
gcc: error: link:: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
mpicc: No such file or directory
```

Requesting the compiler version gives

```
mpicc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: what does `which mpicc` says ? what about `mpicc -showme hello_c.c` ?
note you cannot use `LAM` `mpicc` and expect using `Open MPI`. should you need to install `openmpi-devel` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet `which mpicc` gives `/usr/bin/mpicc`, whereas `mpicc -showme hello.c` gives `gcc -pthread hello.c libtool: link: -pthread -L/usr/lib64 -llammpio -llamf77mpi -lmpi -llam -lutil -ldl `

Comment: so you are using `mpicc` for LAM-MPI (which is now obsolete). you'd rather (install and) use `mpicc` for Open MPI. but if you want to use LAM-MPI, just install `libtool` package and you should be fine.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet You are my hero, thank You very much! Simply installed the openmpi-devel package and everything works.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet One more question: After compiling the program, I runned it using `mpirun -n 4 ./hello`. It gives the desired output `I am rank 0 of 4;
I am rank 1 of 4;
I am rank 2 of 4;
I am rank 3 of 4;
`, but before it warns me several times, that it can't find the file `libpsm_infinipath.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
`, which it seems to search in several directories. Any idea what this could mean and how to fix it?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I just realized another problem: I can not execute the command `mpicc -showme` nor `mpicc -compile_info` anymore, when trying to do so, it returns `bash: /usr/bin/mpicc: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`

Comment: if you do not have any infinipath hardware, then you can ignore the `libpsm_infinipath.so.1` message. if you `export LANG=C`, then the error message will be displayed in plain English, and i will be able to understand it. `rpm -ql openmpi-devel | grep mpicc` will show you the full path to `mpicc`, and you might have to do some update if `/usr/bin/mpicc` is a symlink created by `alternatives`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you very much. Can I switch on some flag to remove the warning? Sorry about the other question, I simply missed to restart the computer in order to adjust the path, it now works fine.

Comment: the right way is to install the missing library :-)
a workaround is to `mpirun --mca mtl ^psm ...`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Superb, thank you again for your great support. It now fully runs as wished

Answer (score 1):

Can you try mpic++ instead:

```
mpic++ hello.c   -o hello
```

It is working on my machine

I used openmpi:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin
```